# how to increment numeric string value in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cursor

I have one android application that returns a string value form a table using cursor (so only string i think) and when i try to parse int, I get catch exception so i can't increment it, all i need is for it to go form 0 to 1,2,3,5,100,923021312 etc. one every time this is called.

If someone knows were I am wrong how to make it to int or how to get it out of the database directly as int

```
public String dmst(String id_math)
{
    String kleidi="";
    int efedriko=0;
    String parousies_max="0";
    final String SQL_code = "SELECT "+DatabaseHelper.Col_PAROUSIES_MAX+" FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2+" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.Col_ID_MATHIMA+" = "+id_math;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQL_code,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            parousies_max = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    try {
        efedriko = Integer.parseInt(parousies_max);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {}
    efedriko=efedriko+1;
```

Comment: First don't catch an exception and just throw it away like that. Print the exception so you can see what the error message actually is. Second, please don't ever ask a question here about an error or exception in your code without posting the actual error message.

Comment: A string in any programming language is not a math thing regardless of if it contains numeric symbols or not. You can convert strings to float, int, long, double and then do math on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line in do loop from getString to getInt method:

FROM:

parousies_max = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));

TO:

parousies_max = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("PAROUSIES_MAX"));